# Is is possible to find position based on distance from origin and heading angle from point a to b?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

[image]

I have graph like this.

Let assume that origin (or anchor) is positioned at (0,0).

We know distance from the anchor to point A and point B. (lets say they are dA and dB).

Then, We know headind angle from point A to Point B. (Lets say it is θ).

Is it possible to get position of Point A or B based on this information?

If I know heaind angle (θ') from anchor to point A, I can use equation

```
x = dA * cos(θ') 
y = dA * sin(θ')
```

to get point A. But, I do not know heading angle from anchor to any of points.

This is where I lost how to approach the problem.

Any advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: No. You cannot have a unique solution. You have four degrees of freedom (x and y values of A and B) and only three constraints(dA, dB, and theta). You can at max get A's position RELATIVE to B, but not their absolute values.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Then, what would be necessary information that I will need? I think heading angle to anchor would be enough?

Comment: Yes, the signed heading angle to any point, A or B, from anchor (considering counterclockwise as positive) will be enough.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Thank you!