# Finding position of A and B based on distance from anchor and heading angle from A to B.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

This is my follow up question from previous question.

previous question: [Is is possible to find position based on distance from origin and heading angle from point a to b?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727359/is-is-possible-to-find-position-based-on-distance-from-origin-and-heading-angle?noredirect=1#comment10019087_4727359)

[image]

I have graph like this.

Let assume that origin (or anchor) is positioned at (0,0).

We know distance from the anchor to point A and point B. (lets say they are dA and dB).

Then, We know headind angle from point A to Point B. (Lets say it is θ).

Then, We know heading angle from Anchor to point A (Lets say is is µ).

Finding position of A is not hard.

```
xA = dA * cos(µ)
yA = dA * sin(µ)
```

Yet, finding position of B is quit ambiguous.

I know heading angle from A to B. Thus, I can find the position of point B relative to Position A and calculate absolute position by

```
xB = xA + (distance from A to B) cos(90-θ)
yB = yA + (distance from A to B) sin(90-θ)
```

How am I able to come up with distance from A to B? I know distance from anchor to B but not distance from A to B.

Does my approach on this question correct?

Any advice would be very appreciated!